# Bootstrap Modal-related Memory Leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Please understand that it will be difficult for me to post snippets of code, but the problem is easy to summarize.

1. A modal becomes visible.
2. I click anywhere OUTSIDE of the modal (we are still in the modal here, and experiencing zero lag).
3. The modal is closed.
4. Suddenly everything is very laggy, until I click on any element that IS NOT bound to a .click listener, after which the lag is completely gone.

Because of step #4, it seems to behave similarly to a recursive function. When I finally click on something not listening for a click, it returns all the way back up and all is well. Until then, I just burrow deeper into the rabbit hole.

**Notes:**

- This applies to all modals in the DOM.
- If a modal is closed using ESC or the 'Close' button, there is no lag. The issue only arises when I click outside of the modal.
- I'm not dynamically creating anything here, not even the modals, so I don't have a straightforward idea of why memory usage would be increasing.
- There is never more than one modal open at a time (tested via extensive logging).
- I happen to have 'data-background="static"' set so that the modals don't auto-close when you click outside of them, but this doesn't have any effect on the issue. With or without it, the same issue crops up.

Comment: Do you add event listeners to modal.close event? What browser you use? Do u change css styles of modal dialog?

Comment: Tell us about your PC, maybe it far back in the past? :)

Comment: I think at the very least, we'll need to see the code you use when you click outside of the dialog.

Comment: @luther I have no listeners for modal.close, I'm using the latest version of Chrome, and I am not changing the css of modals.

Comment: @imtheman I don't have any code related to clicking outside of the dialog. No click listeners, nothing.